# Ubuntu PowerEdge T110

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge

I just got a Dell PowerEdge T110 server. I moved the boot order to CD - HDD - NIC, then installed Ubuntu 10.10, Desktop Ed. I chose install alongside other OS (even though there was none), then chose use entire partition. It showed that Ubuntu would use 160 of the 160 available GB. It installed, updated (while installing), then said, need to eject and restart, as usual. It restarted, but to a blank screen. No output whatsoever. Not even BIOS. Just blank. The monitor isn't even woken from sleep. Power cycled, still doing it. Tested the monitor with a laptop, and it is fine. What on earth is going on here?

Comment: Do the fans spin up?

Comment: Yes, it comes all to life, just no output. And I have to hold down the power button for a couple of seconds to shut it down, as if it was in an OS. I have a terrible feeling I incorrectly installed the OS. Should I have installed it by some built in loader?

Comment: Holding the power button doesn't actually power off the whole machine on almost all servers. Pull the plug for at least 2 minutes, plug it back in, see if it works then.

Comment: Didn't work, had to reset the NVRAM, via it's motherboard jumper! WHEW!

Comment: @Chris S, Thank you though, I did try that, and I did unplug it and push the power button to drain it a different time, neither worked, unfortunately.

Comment: FWIW, I found the BIOS on the T110 dodgy. It would not recognize an Adaptec 5405Z even though a lowly SC440 I had lying around had no problem with it. I ended up sending the T110 back to DELL.

Comment: @Jason, I was just about there. Damn thing was driving me crazy. As soon as I set it up on the network, the switch started acting funny. Seems to be good now, but if it acts up again in the next couple of days, it's gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reset the NVRAM via the motherboard jumper.